# Unable to change rating bar color

Tags: android, ratingbar

I'm using the following code for rating bar.

```
<RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:stepSize="1.0"
            android:background="@color/yellow"/>
```

The problem is that I'm unable to change the color of stars in rating bar. Even when i tried setting background. How can I change the color of star?

Comment: Why not try images instead of rating bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it....

```
android:progressTint="@color/color"
```

**or**

you can use it...

Use **android:theme attribute:**

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.Rating" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="colorAccent">@color/rating</item>
</style>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
android:theme="@style/Theme.Rating"
android:numStars="5"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: its not changing bro

Comment: if you think my answer is useful then vote it as favourite answer so others can use it..

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest create three star images yello_full.png, yellow_half.png and yellow_empty.png . now put these images in drawable folder.

Create a xml file in drawable and put this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
android:id="@android:id/background"
android:drawable="@drawable/yellow_empty" />

<item 
android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" 
android:drawable="@drawable/yellow_half" />

<item 
android:id="@android:id/progress"    
android:drawable="@drawable/yello_full" />
</layer-list>
```

now in your rating bar add this

```
  <RatingBar 
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar_yellow"/>
```

and here you go.. Enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating drawables you can change it by setting color filter. 
Example

```
ratingWidget.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Here color is the color you want to set to the widget.